# event handler cannot be executed

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I got a problem in my WP-7 app. 
I have an event when I read from the cloud - OpenReadCompletedEventHandler,
but somehow when the event occurs the EventHandler cannot be executed.

Here is my functions:

```
public void SetCategories()
    //set the Companies table from Shret.net DataBase
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://api.sherut.net/?method=Category");
            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);

            try
            {
                webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = null;
        try
        {
            serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Categories));
            var categories = (Categories)serializer.ReadObject(e.Result);
            //  foreach (Company c in companies.data)

            //  MessageBox.Show(c.Name + " " + c.CompanyID+" "+c.CompanyGUID);
            //לכתוב לבסיס נתונים באפליקציה
            BuildCategoriesDB(); //build the local data base
            AddCategoriesData(categories);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

It reads from the cloud, but it doesn't go inside the handler: webClient_OpenReadCompleted

Comment: I dropped your code into a new project and it worked for me. Have you got a complete repro?

Comment: How do you know it "reads from the cloud"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure the event is being created and "thrown".